# Deploy an older version of Elastic Search in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I want to deploy version 2.3 of Elastic Search in AWS.
But it looks like I am only able to deploy version 5.1+ .
However, I have already a cluster with version 2.3 running in my other account, I just want to migrate accounts and have same setup without all the work to upgrade the clients using the cluster.
Technically it should be possible since I have a cluster running already with that version ...
Is there a way?

Comment: I think they removed the ability to create instances of older versions due to a licensing dispute with Elastic.